# SharePoint Online Search and PowerBI Links Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online

I wonder if anyone can help with this.

We have a standard SharePoint Online site which has a document library.   In the document library, we want to create links to PowerBI reports that are held centrally in our PowerBI portal (https://app.powerbi.com).  We go into the doc lib and choose New...Link then in the Link box we put the URL directly to the PowerBI report.

[image]

The item in the doc library has a "Name" of the [report name].url as below
[image]

From the main SharePoint home page when we search the site for the report name, we can see it appear as [report name].url in the results that filter under the search box but when we click on it, it just tries to download a file called [report name].url, it doesn't take you directly to the PowerBI report in the portal.

Subsequently, if you go into the actual document library and search for the report in the  "Search this library" box then when it appears, it DOES take you directly to the PowerBI report.

We want users to be able to search for reports in PowerBI from the main home page search and when they click on the results, it takes you directly to the PowerBI report.

Am I missing something?

What is the best way to store links to PowerBI reports so that users can surface them in the main home page search ("Search this site") box and be able to take them straight to the Report.

Any advice would be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to search for Power BI reports, is to use the organisation wide search within Microsoft Search. When you search in a SharePoint site via the top bar, if you click "Organization" it will show you results from the entire organisation. The organization search page has a Power BI vertical:

[image]